# How do I attatch text information to a specific date using Calender View

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, calendar

I added the calender view to my black activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Homepage">

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calender_view"
    android:onClick="hoursLog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</CalendarView>
```

What I want to do now is basically be able to select a date from the calender and enter numbers (hours logged) which is tied to that specific date kind of like how a reminder functions.

I know I have to create a new activity and an intent but I'm lost as to how I can 'attach' that activity page to a specific date. Like having it function as a part of the calender and not a new entity entirely.

I got this far in my .java file

```
public class Homepage extends ActionBarActivity {


public void hoursLog (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayHoursLog.class);
    CalendarView cView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calender_view);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check and use custom AdapterCalendar(http://droidwalk.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html):

DateModel.class

```
private String mTextNote;
 private Date mDateChoose;
 public String getTextNote(){return mTextNote};
 public Date getDateChoose(){return mDateChoose};
 public void setTextNote(String textNote){mTextNote = textNote;};
 public void setDateChoose(String dateChoose){mDateChoose = dateChoose;};
```

after : i click calendar, check if calendar == getDateChoose; show textNote.